# Подключения таблицы стилей для одного блока CSS

Tags: html, css

Есть

```
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="content"></div>
 <div id="slider"></div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
```

К этому index.html подключена таблица стилей `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />`.

Также есть еще таблица `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">`.

Как мне global.css применить ТОЛЬКО для `#slider`?

Comment: а зачем 2-ой подключать global.css, если можно в одном style.css
Для блока #slider - у вас уже используется id, он уникален

Comment: А если у меня 4 слайдера и + 1 слайдер, а в нем еще карусель, и на каждый слайд и карусель свой скин... вообщем как-то так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проследить, чтобы в `global.css` не было упоминания `#header`, `#content`, `#footer`.

Comment: и подключить global.css после style.css(если в нем есть #slider)

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас оба файла применяются на одной странице, то сделать так, чтобы файл работал для определённого куска html-кода, нельзя.

Да и в сss в этом совершенно нет необходимости, потому что есть селекторы, которые выбирают нужный блок и применяют к нему стили, а также есть возможность повысить приоритет селекторов в нужном месте при необходимости.