# Применить стили Bootstrap только для определенного блока

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как применить стили Bootstrap только для определенного блока?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/376981/Подключения-таблицы-стилей-для-одного-блока-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы советовал достать нужную вам часть `CSS` из `Bootstrap` и завязаться на уникальный селектор нужного вам блока. По другому вы не отделите стили  –  они в любом случае будут применяться на весь документ.

Comment: пробывал, но там так много всего что очень сильно запутаюсь что и для чего
~150kb кода

Comment: а как сделать чтоб мои файлы были важнее этого bootstrap  чтоб мои стили\темы .. выполнялись в главную(то есть только они).
-от bootstrap мне нужно лишь для формы чтоб вкладки её показать